# How to show at most 5 numbers in a pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I have a pagination and I want to achieve and limit it to 5 page numbers,

See below:

Examples:

```
 PREVIOUS 1 2 3 4 5 NEXT
 PREVIOUS 20 21 22 23 ... 39 NEXT
 PREVIOUS 59 ... 81 82 83 84 NEXT
```

Just five page number that they should be display.
Which part of the code should I alter and modify?

I am having trouble with the combination.

```
 <?php
 /* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous buttons
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<a class='disabled'><buttons disabled>previous</buttons></a>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<a class='current'><buttons style='background-color:#CEF6F5'>$counter</buttons></a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<a class='current'><buttons style='background-color:#CEF6F5'>$counter</buttons></a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=1\"> 1 </a>";
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=2\"> 2 </a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<a class='current'><buttons style='background-color:#CEF6F5'>$counter</buttons></a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<a class='current'><buttons style='background-color:#CEF6F5'>$counter</buttons></a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next buttons
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a class='buttons' href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<a class='buttons'>next</a>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>
```

I am having problem tracing the limit for displaying page number.

Comment: you need to modify the code after the comment `//enough pages to hide some`

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am doing it in a couple of days and I can't figure it out. jaromanda

Comment: _"fixed only"_? Fixed what?

Comment: Oh, and since there's no [tag:JavaScript], [tag:jQuery], or [tag:mySQL] in the question, I removed those tags.

Comment: fixed means.. its pagination shows 5 page numbers only if there is a lot of record to be display.. Cerbus

Comment: which one there Cerbrus?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.
You have to pass your current page number and total number of pages to the function.

```
function pageRange(page,pageCount){

var start = page-2,
    end = page+2;

if(end>pageCount){
    start-=(end-pageCount);
    end=pageCount;
}
if(start<=0){
    end+=((start-1)*(-1));
    start=1;
}

end = end>pageCount?pageCount:end;

return {start:start, end:end};
}
```

EDIT: check out this fiddle i made https://jsfiddle.net/qsLp6ajL/2/

Comment: So I am going to add this function inside my pagination code?

Comment: ya call this function passing the parameters. It works fine for me.

Comment: can you take a look my code above what represent the `pageCount` in your function?

Comment: Mind you, it calculates the start and end page range values for the page that you are currently in. Linking it with the pagination has to be done by you.

Comment: your $lastpage variable seems to store the pageCount value.

Comment: Yes I tried. `pageCount` $lastpage `start` $next `end`$previous

Answer (score 1):

I used below code for my wordpress plugin to display pagination and display data in table. You can use this according to your mysql query.

```
<?php echo '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'; ?>
    <col width="10%" />
    <col width="25%" />
    <col width="25%" />
    <col width="30%" />
    <col width="10%" />

<?php 
        echo '<tr class="st_th" height="30px">';
        echo '<th class="th_id"> ID</th>';      
        echo '<th class="st_th1"> Name</th>';
        echo '<th class="st_th1"> Phone</th>';
        echo '<th class="st_th1">Address</th>'; 
        echo '<th class="st_th1">Details</th>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
        global $wpdb;
        $num_rec_per_page=4;

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}addressbook LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 


        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql); 

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr height="25px">';
                echo '<td width="10%" class="fast_t">' . $row->id. '</td>'; 
                echo '<td class="st_th1" style="padding-left:5px; width:200px">' . $row->f_name, ' ', $row->m_name, ' ', $row->l_name . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="st_th1" style="padding-left:5px;width:200px">' . $row->phone . '</td>';        
                echo '<td class="st_th1" style="padding-left:5px;width:200px">' . $row->address . '</td>';
                //echo '<td style="padding-left:5px">' . $row->address . '</td>';

                $pages2 = get_pages(array(
                    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
                    'meta_value' => 'user_list_page.php'
                ));
                foreach($pages2 as $page2){
                    //echo $page->ID.'<br />';

                }
                if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();  
                }
                if ($user_ID==$row->id) {
                    # code...

                    echo '<td '.$attributes.'>';
                        //echo '<a href="'. get_permalink( $page1->ID).'&id=' . $row->id . '"> Edit</a>|';
                         if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) { 
                        echo '<a href="'. get_permalink( $page->ID).'?id=' . $row->id . '"> Details</a>';
                        //echo 'permalinks enabled'; 
                    } else {
                        echo '<a href="'. get_permalink( $page->ID).'&id=' . $row->id . '"> Details</a>';
                    }
                 echo'</td>';
                }
                if ($user_ID!=$row->id) {
                     echo '<td '.$attributes.'><a href="'. get_permalink( $page->ID).'&id=' . $row->id . '"> Details</a></td>';
                }

            echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix."addressbook"; 
 $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
 $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
 $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
 $aaa = get_permalink( $page2->ID);?>
 <div class="pagination">
 <?php echo "<a href='".$aaa."&page=1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
         if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) { 
                        echo "<a href='".$aaa."?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
                        //echo 'permalinks enabled'; 
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href='".$aaa."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
                    }

    }; 
     if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) { 
                        echo "<a href='".$aaa."?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page

                    } else {
                        echo "<a href='".$aaa."&page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page
                    }

    echo '</div>';?>
    </div>
```